# Почему width в css "сильнее" атрибута width?

Tags: html, css

Приветствую. Хочу перебить ширину, заданную в css в коде html прописав `width="200"`, но не удается - почему? Мне html Всегда казался "сильнее" стилевых свойств или все дело в `js`?

```js
$(function() {

  $('#container').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    columnWidth: 70
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#container {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
}
.item {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #CCC;
}
.item.w2 {
  width: 130px;
}
.item.h2 {
  height: 130px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://masonry.desandro.com/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div width="200" class="item w2"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item w2"></div>
  <div class="item h2"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item h2"></div>
  <div class="item w2 h2"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item h2"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item w2"></div>
  <div class="item h2"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item h2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Насколько мне известно, атрибут width допустим только в тегах img, table и td.
Width у div'а игнорируется.
[image: Width у div'а игнорируется.]

Для тегов используется CSS свойство width.
Чтобы перебить стили селектора можно использовать атрибут style="width:200px".

Answer (score 1):

Не используйте атрибуты `width`, теги `strong`, `u`, `i` итп для стилизации.

Для этого есть **CSS**!

Comment: Объясните, почему не использовать теги strong, u, i ?

Comment: Мне тоже интересно.

Comment: @soledar10, потому что они в html5 объявлены deprecated (а `u` так вообще исключён из стандарта) и для этого есть css.

Comment: @Qwertiy - тег u - да это deprecated, а вот strong and i - разве deprecated?

Comment: @soledar10, насколько я знаю, тег `u` - это (уже) несуществующий, а вот `i` - deprecated (правда, вот-вот получит новую жизнь в роли иконки). `strong` - нормальный.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить `width="200"` на `style="width:200px"`

Answer (score -4):

Добавь `!important` к стилю которым переопределяешь

Comment: Поясните автору, что именно означает это свойство и где можно об этом почитать.